# logic within c# OnEventReached method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Can someone please explain me the importance of below statement while raising an event.

```
   EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> handler = ThresholdReached;
```

As we are simply assigning the Threshold event to handler, why can't we just simply call like ThresholdReached(this, e)

```
    protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> handler = ThresholdReached;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> ThresholdReached;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having this first line protects from race conditions in multi threaded application.

Imagine if some other thread unsubscribed from event just after you checked if it is not null.

And checking for null is necessary because event without any handlers is null and you would get NullReferenceException by calling such event.

So to be precise.

This code does not check for null and may throw NullReferenceException:

```
protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
{
    ThresholdReached(this, e);
}
```

This is dangerous due to possible race condition and possibly may also throw an exception:

```
protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ThresholdReached != null)
         ThresholdReached(this, e);
}
```

EDIT (to better explain behavior of local variable):

Having this assignment creates a local copy of the event maintaining its state. So if any thread unsubscribes from event local copy remains the same throughout the rest of the method call. In other words the delegate behaves like copying a structure not like copying a reference.

Below code would print text:

```
        // let's assume ThresholdReached is null
        ThresholdReached += MyHandler;
        EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> localCopy = ThresholdReached ;
        ThresholdReached -= Program_SthEvent;
        if (localCopy != null)
            Console.WriteLine("we have a copy!");
```

Notice how `localCopy` remains state and value;

Comment: Partially answered my question. But If that is the case, then how does the below statement help us solving a race condition and ensures us it never throws any exception? After all it is just an assignment.
EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> handler = ThresholdReached;

Comment: Edited my answer to better explain what assignment does

Comment: @zeroCool - It's important to know that delegates are value types so an assignment creates a copy of all of the attached handlers and that means the local copy will not change even if the source delegate has its handlers removed.

Comment: @Enigmativity that was the point of the last edit. I feel that you put it more clearly with few words than I did with an example. However do you have any prove/documentation link that delegate IS a value type? I know that is behaves like value type but I cannot find any official docs. System.Delegate is a class that inherits from Object so it should I would assume that it would behave like an object. EventHandler is a `delegate` that could be thought of like built in type (like `int`) but on the other hand Int32 is a struct unlike System.Delegate.

Comment: `System.Delegate` is one of the special types, like `System.Enum` and `System.ValueType`. It doesn't behave like `System.Object` even though it inherits from it. It has special compiler support. I shouldn't have said it is a value type. Instead it has value type semantics.

Comment: @pg0xC - Sorry, forgot to "at" message you. Please see above.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much guys pg0xC and Enigmativity. This has been troubling my mind for some time, its all clear now !!